# Can I write a comma straight after a dot? in business card

Tags: american-english

Firstly please excuse any grammatical errors I might have while writing this question, English isn't my native language nor is it my first but I'll try my best.
Alright to the question,

I'm about to print business card and I don't have enough room to write Street so I write st. I saw many business cards that every piece of information is being divided by a comma for example, Rothschild 22nd Street, London, United Kingdom, P.O.B. 23123

Now in my case I don't have enough room to write the word street (btw, should I write St. in a business card or does it make look less professional when I shorten the word?)
So for example my address would be *Rothschild 22nd St., London, United Kingdom, P.O.B. 23123* Is that correct formatting for a business card (using , after .?)
And is using st. rather than street makes it look bad?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with following "St." with a comma, just as there is nothing wrong with following "e.g." with a comma. Whether to use "St." or "Street" on a business card is a style/judgment call that you'll just have to make for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I worked in the typesetting department of an Irish Government office for several years, and we used "open punctuation" when it came to addresses, abbreviations, etc.  So we would have used this format for the above address:

Rothschild 22nd St

London

UK

POB 23123

I'd prefer "Street" rather than "St" but that can be a matter of personal taste or space limitations. Obviously, if the address is to be written on one line only, commas are vital.

Comment: I think his question is, what punctuation to use when it is all on one line ... Rothschild 22nd St, London, UK, POB 23123

Answer (score 0):

You may use comma after the . since its not a full stop/period.

As for shortening the word street as St, it's perfectly fine according to me.

Hope this helps!!